# Unity: Change Desktop Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") to Mobile Button Press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, input, mobile

I already created a Desktop 2D Platformer Game that can jump dynamically (from short to long maximum jump) depending on how long you pressed the spacebar using Input.GetButtonDown("Jump").

I want to create a mobile version of my game. So I just want to make a solution on **how I can create a function/method that returns boolean same as Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")** when the button is pressed in the Mobile Screen User Interface.

Or can someonw explain how Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") works deeper? Like how many frames it will be called when spacebar was hold pressed. So that I can make a function like this but for mobile button touch. Thank you so much.

**Edit:**
I already tried using onClick event from Button or Input.GetTouch (Tested in actual Mobile device) but is not the same output when using Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") from Desktop using spacebar. When I used onClick and GetTouch the character only jump very short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")` is the same as calling `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`.
These strings are mapped in Unity project settings you can actually change their values at (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input).

You can achieve the same effect with UI buttons you need to use the onClick event (player have to tap on the button), or with a screen tap anywhere on the screen using `Input.GetTouch`

Comment: I already tried this way using onClick event or Input.GetTouch but is not the same output when using Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"). When I used onClick and GetTouch the character only jump very short.

Comment: Then you need on hold, check if the touch is being held down or not via `TouchPhase`, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html